# UIPinchGestureRecognizer acting funny when Image gets enlarged too big

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-graphics

I have a simple app where I attach a UIPinchGestureRecognizer and UIPanGestureRecognizer to an imageView so I can drag and scale it. I have made it so the imageView can be partially moved off the screen and minimized off the display, but a small 75 pixel part of the image remains on the display so the image can be dragged back onto it. So for instance if I try to drag the imageView off the right part of the display, it will stop when 75 pixels of the imageView is remaining, leaving just enough space for me to drag it back. Same concept with scaling, the boundary frame I create prevents the imageView from being minimized off the display.

Anyhow, I'm having this problem with my boundary code in my UIPinchGestureRecognizer delegate method. The way I'm doing the boundary is I'm creating a frame that is a replica of the imageViews superview - except it's pushed in 75 pixels on each side and top and bottom. I check to see if the imageView is NOT intersecting with this frame, and then I know it's reached one of the boundaries on the right / left or top / bottom. It works for the most part, however when I enlarge the image to be quite large (usually somewhere over 1000 by 1000), the boundary doesn't work - if I do an ultra quick minimize scale, the imageView gets pushed completely off the screen so I can't drag it back.

I'm just wondering why this is happening. Does it have to do with the image size getting too large? Or is it a flaw in my code? (I've listed below). If anyone can help would be appreciated.

```
- (void)scale:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)sender 
{
    if([sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) 
    {
        lastScale = [sender scale];
    }

    if ([sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || 
        [sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) 
    {
        CGFloat currentScale = [[[sender view].layer valueForKeyPath:@"transform.scale"] floatValue];
        CGFloat newScale = 1 -  (lastScale - [sender scale]);// * (CropThePhotoViewControllerPinchSpeed);    
        newScale = MAX(newScale, CropThePhotoViewControllerMinScale / currentScale);

        CGFloat scaledWidth = newScale * sender.view.frame.size.width;
        CGFloat scaledHeight = newScale * sender.view.frame.size.height;

        CGRect translatedRect = CGRectMake(sender.view.frame.origin.x, sender.view.frame.origin.y, scaledWidth, scaledHeight);
        CGRect boundaryRect = CGRectMake(sender.view.superview.frame.origin.x + CropThePhotoViewControllerBoundaryBuffer, sender.view.superview.frame.origin.y + CropThePhotoViewControllerBoundaryBuffer, sender.view.superview.frame.size.width - (CropThePhotoViewControllerBoundaryBuffer * 2), sender.view.superview.frame.size.height - (CropThePhotoViewControllerBoundaryBuffer * 2));

        if (!(!CGRectIntersectsRect(boundaryRect,translatedRect) && newScale < 1))
        {
            CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformScale([[sender view] transform], newScale, newScale);
            [[sender view] setTransform: transform];
            lastScale = [sender scale];;
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what was wrong. For this line of code, I was setting the x and y values incorrectly:

```
CGRect translatedRect = CGRectMake(sender.view.frame.origin.x, sender.view.frame.origin.y, scaledWidth, scaledHeight);
```

It should be:

```
CGRect translatedRect = CGRectMake(sender.view.frame.origin.x + (((sender.view.frame.size.width - scaledWidth) / 2)), sender.view.frame.origin.y + (((sender.view.frame.size.height - scaledHeight) / 2)), scaledWidth, scaledHeight);
```

I wasn't accounting for the fact that the origin was going to move when the imageview was shrunk.

I made this change, and actually updated the method to be improved. Now instead of just not performing a scale if the user tries minimizing beyond the boundary, instead I move the imageView right to the border. This is smoother and ultimately better imo. It's working pretty well after testing, but if anyone sees any bugs please let me know:

```
- (void)scale:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)sender 
{
    if([sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) 
    {
        previousScale = [sender scale];
    }


    if ([sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || 
        [sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) 
    {
        CGFloat nextScale = 1 -  (previousScale - [sender scale]);// * (CropThePhotoViewControllerPinchSpeed); 

        nextScale = MAX(nextScale, CropThePhotoViewControllerMinScale / [[[sender view].layer valueForKeyPath:@"transform.scale"] floatValue]);

        CGFloat scaledWidth = nextScale * sender.view.frame.size.width;
        CGFloat scaledHeight = nextScale * sender.view.frame.size.height;
        CGFloat currentScale = [sender scale];

        CGRect translatedRect = CGRectMake(sender.view.frame.origin.x + (((sender.view.frame.size.width - scaledWidth) / 2)), sender.view.frame.origin.y + (((sender.view.frame.size.height - scaledHeight) / 2)), scaledWidth, scaledHeight);
        CGRect boundaryRect = CGRectMake(sender.view.superview.frame.origin.x + CropThePhotoViewControllerBoundaryBuffer, sender.view.superview.frame.origin.y + CropThePhotoViewControllerBoundaryBuffer, sender.view.superview.frame.size.width - (CropThePhotoViewControllerBoundaryBuffer * 2), sender.view.superview.frame.size.height - (CropThePhotoViewControllerBoundaryBuffer * 2));

        if ((!CGRectIntersectsRect(boundaryRect,translatedRect)) && (nextScale < 1))        
        {
            CGFloat leftScaledEdge, rightScaledEdge, topScaledEdge, bottomScaledEdge;
            CGFloat leftBoundary, rightBoundary, topBoundary, bottomBoundary;
            CGFloat nextXScale, nextYScale;

            nextXScale = CGFLOAT_MIN;
            nextYScale = CGFLOAT_MIN;

            rightScaledEdge = translatedRect.origin.x + translatedRect.size.width;
            leftScaledEdge = translatedRect.origin.x;
            bottomScaledEdge = translatedRect.origin.y + translatedRect.size.height;
            topScaledEdge = translatedRect.origin.y;

            leftBoundary = boundaryRect.origin.x;
            rightBoundary = boundaryRect.origin.x + boundaryRect.size.width; 
            topBoundary = boundaryRect.origin.y;
            bottomBoundary = boundaryRect.origin.y + boundaryRect.size.height;  

            if (rightScaledEdge < leftBoundary || leftScaledEdge > rightBoundary)
            {
                if (rightScaledEdge < leftBoundary)
                {
                    CGFloat adjustedWidth = sender.view.frame.size.width - fabsf((leftBoundary - (sender.view.frame.origin.x + sender.view.frame.size.width)));
                    nextXScale = (nextScale * (adjustedWidth)) / scaledWidth;
                }
                else
                {
                    CGFloat adjustedWidth = sender.view.frame.size.width - fabsf((rightBoundary - sender.view.frame.origin.x));
                    nextXScale = (nextScale * (adjustedWidth)) / scaledWidth;
                }
            }

            if (bottomScaledEdge < topBoundary || topScaledEdge > bottomBoundary)
            {
                if (bottomScaledEdge < topBoundary)
                {
                    CGFloat adjustedHeight = sender.view.frame.size.height - fabsf((topBoundary - (sender.view.frame.origin.y + sender.view.frame.size.height)));
                    nextYScale = (nextScale * (adjustedHeight)) / scaledHeight;
                }
                else
                {
                    CGFloat adjustedHeight = sender.view.frame.size.height - fabsf((bottomBoundary - sender.view.frame.origin.y));
                    nextYScale = (nextScale * (adjustedHeight)) / scaledHeight;

                }
            }

            if (nextXScale >= nextYScale)
            {
                nextScale = nextXScale;
            }
            else 
            {
                nextScale = nextYScale;
            }

            currentScale = nextScale - 1 + previousScale;
        }

        CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformScale([[sender view] transform], nextScale, nextScale);
        [[sender view] setTransform: transform];
        previousScale = currentScale;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I have noticed that I have to check for NaN (not a number) results from scaling, and then deal with them separately.  Use isnan() to check.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried looking for any NaNs and none did show up. My problem was else where, I wrote about it in my answer.